# convert bounding box coordinates to x,y pairs

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, bounding-box, cartesian

I have a bounding box coordinates in this format [x, y, width, height],

how can I get all the x and y pairs from it?

the result is going to be in this format [(x1,y1),(x2,y2),...,(xn,yn)]

thanks in advance!

Comment: `coords = [(i,j) for i in range(x,x+width) for j in range(y,y+width)]` obviously this could generate a quite large set of data depending on your dataset. If your using this to check collisions it would probably be faster to instead check `x<posx<x+width and y<posy<y+height`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand your data description correctly, but here's an example that might fit:

```
data = [
    [1, 2, 100, 100],
    [3, 4, 100, 100],
    [5, 6, 200, 200],
]

result = [tuple(x[:2]) for x in data]
```

Result:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding of your question here is the answer:

```py
data = [1, 2, 100, 100]    ## x=1, y=2, width=100, height=100
coordinates = [[x, y], [x + width, y], [x + width, y + height], [x, y + height]]
```

Result with all 4 coordinates of the bounding box:

```py
[[1, 2], [101, 2], [101, 102], [1, 102]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
data = [
[1, 2, 100, 100],
[3, 4, 100, 100],
[5, 6, 200, 200],
]

answer = []
for n in data:
  answer.append(n[0:2])

print(answer)
```